# Remove some privacy options in GNOME Settings application

Tags: camera, fedora, gnome, microphone, privacy

Can anyone advise me how to removeLocation Services, Camera and Microphone privacy options in GNOME Settings application? I'm running Fedora 33. I know that these options restrict access for sandboxed apps only and don't make sense for me since I'm not using Flatpak apps. Moreover, the Microphone privacy option spontaneously turns on after rebooting or waking up and it drives me crazy. In Ubuntu Camera and Microphone options are missing, so I think it's possible to remove them on the Fedora as well.

[image: Privacy options to remove]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box using some kind of secret setting or some hidden API. The only way to achieve this, is by grabbing the source package, removing the code that adds those panels to the window and then rebuilding the package yourself and installing it locally.

This is also what Ubuntu does on its own packages; you can find the patch here: https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/tree/debian/patches/0020-Disable-non-working-camera-microphones-panels.patch?h=ubuntu/groovy-devel